# Finding the first non-zero year in data frame for multiple variables using tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
test <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 5)),
                   Year = 2000 + c(1,3,5,2,3,5,6,1,2,3,4,5),
                   var1 = sample(0:2, replace = TRUE, size = 12, prob = c(0.6, 0.3, 0.1)),
                   var2 = sample(0:2, replace = TRUE, size = 12, prob = c(0.6, 0.3, 0.1)))
```

I need to the first year that each variable (`var1` and `var2`) is non-zero within each id group.

I know how to find the row number of the first non-zero row:

```
temp <- function(a) ifelse(length(head(which(a>0),1))==0,0,head(which(a>0),1))

test2 <- test %>% group_by(id) %>% 
mutate_at(vars(var1:var2),funs(temp)) %>%
filter(row_number()==1) %>% select (-year)

     id  var1  var2
1     1   0     1
2     2   1     2
3     3   1     1
```

However, I am not sure how to match the row number back to the year variable so that I will know exactly when did the `var1` and `var2` turn non-zero, instead of only having the row numbers.

This is what I want:

```
     id  var1  var2
1     1   0     2001
2     2   2002  2003
3     3   2001  2001
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may do the following:

```
test %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_at(vars(var1:var2), funs(Year[. > 0][1]))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#      id  var1  var2
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1    NA  2001
# 2     2  2002  2003
# 3     3  2001  2001
```

That is, `. > 0` gives a logical vector with `TRUE` whenever a value is positive, then we select all the corresponding years, and lastly pick only the first one.

That's very similar to your approach. Notice that due to using `summarise` I no longer need `filter(row_number()==1) %>% select (-year)`. Also, my function corresponding to `temp` is more concise.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach gathering everything into a big long file first:

```
test %>%
  gather(var, value, var1:var2) %>%
  filter(value != 0) %>%
  group_by(id, var) %>%
  summarise(Year = min(Year)) %>%
  spread(var, Year)

## A tibble: 3 x 3
## Groups:   id [3]
#     id  var1  var2
#* <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  1.00    NA  2001
#2  2.00  2002  2003
#3  3.00  2001  2001
```

And a base R version for fun:

```
tmp <- cbind(test[c("id", "Year")], stack(test[c("var1","var2")]))
tmp <- tmp[tmp$values != 0,]
tmp <- aggregate(Year ~ id + ind, data=tmp, FUN=min)
reshape(tmp[c("id","ind","Year")], idvar="id", timevar="ind", direction="wide")
```